# Dynamic (database) IP Blocking with SQL on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am using IIS7.5 URL rewrite module to look up redirect and rewrites in the SQL database attached to my website - and am now trying to use the same system to look up a list of IP address I wish to block (return 403).

I have a table of IPs (in SQL server) which is continually updated (outside of the remit of this question) and I want IIS to pass the IP address of the current request to a stored procedure which will then return a Pass/Fail on whether to allow the request to continue or return a HTTP 403.

I don't seem to be able to work out how to configure this in IIS.

Many thanks